# How Can I add DropBox as a "Place" in Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-office, dropbox, microsoft-office-2016

I would like to add DropBox as a "Place" that will show up as one of the defaults in the Save/Open menu in Office 2016. The `Add a Place` function provided only offers Office 365 SharePoint and OneDrive as options. [Instructions found to pin the location](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/office-2016-add-dropbox) have not worked for me and the [DropBox forum](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205060469-dropbox-with-office-2016-and-Win-10) post doesn't make things sound so promising.

Does anyone know of a way to get this to work until either DropBox or MS gets their act together?

Answer (score 2):

You can add Dropbox to Office 2016 (tested on Windows 10 Pro) by adding 3 registry settings ([original article](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/add-dropbox-to-office-2013)). Note that the article talks about Office 2013, but it works fine for Office 2016.

1. Open Regedit and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage`
2. Right-click "Cloud Storage" to create a New>Key with a unique GUID (example uses: `0627ecb4-3ede-422a-8b23-954e7b6bed29`) [you can get randomly generated keys online].
3. Right-click the new key you just created and then click Add>New>String to add each of the following three Strings directly under this key with the names `DisplayName`, `LearnMoreURL` and `LocalFolderRoot`.
   [you will need to go through this 3 times, once for each new String]
4. Assign each of the new Strings the values as follows [don't use the quotes]:

   - DisplayName -- "Dropbox"
   - LearnMoreURL -- "https://www.dropbox.com"
   - LocalFolderRoot -- "C:\{path}\Dropbox" {whatever your path is on your machine}

Under Windows 10, no need to reboot. When you choose "Open" or "Save" in Word, for example, then click "Add a Place" and Dropbox will appear as an option. Here's a dump of my export of that key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage\0627ecb4-3ede-422a-8b23-954e7b6bed29]
"DisplayName"="Dropbox"
"LearnMoreURL"="https://www.dropbox.com"
"LocalFolderRoot"="C:\\Dropbox"
```

Comment: There's another way to add Dropbox, Google Drive, and Sharepoint as cloud storage options. Open an Office product (Word, Excel, etc.). Click File menu (showing Save, Save As, etc). Click **Account** and sign into your Microsoft account. This will show _Connected Services_. You can "Add a Service" which includes both Dropbox and Google Drive. Tested in Office Plus 2013

Comment: this does not seem to work for me with Office 2016 and [this](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/office-2016-add-dropbox) article says that this doesnt work in general on Office 2016 anymore. Is this solution still viable or does something have changed?

Answer (score -1):

Following on from tabletguy's info, and Thomas van Hek's batch file, I have made a batch script which works for our users on Windows 10, Office 365 x64.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO.
ECHO This file modifies the registry in Windows 10 to add Dropbox as a save/open location within Office 2016.
ECHO.
ECHO     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
ECHO     ^|       You must have opened this by right-clicking and clicking "Run as administrator"       ^|
ECHO     ^|  If you see ERROR: Acccess is denied, it's because you opened by double-clicking as normal  ^|
ECHO     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

ECHO.
ECHO Please verify this is the correct path to your Dropbox folder ( note there's no trailling backslash \ )
ECHO.
SET "dropboxdir=%userprofile%\Dropbox"
ECHO %dropboxdir%
ECHO.

ECHO Enter the corrected path, or press ENTER if it is correct:
SET /P dropboxdir=

REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage\eee1e7ca-caac-4cf9-ab6c-7160f41e36f3"
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage\eee1e7ca-caac-4cf9-ab6c-7160f41e36f3" /v "Description" /d "Dropbox complicates the way you create, share and collaborate. Bring your photos, docs, and videos anywhere and keep your files safe."
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage\eee1e7ca-caac-4cf9-ab6c-7160f41e36f3" /v "DisplayName" /d "Dropbox"
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage\eee1e7ca-caac-4cf9-ab6c-7160f41e36f3" /v "LearnMoreURL" /d "https://www.dropbox.com/"
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage\eee1e7ca-caac-4cf9-ab6c-7160f41e36f3" /v "LocalFolderRoot" /d "%dropboxdir%"
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage\eee1e7ca-caac-4cf9-ab6c-7160f41e36f3" /v "ManageURL" /d "https://www.dropbox.com/account"
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage\eee1e7ca-caac-4cf9-ab6c-7160f41e36f3" /v "Url48x48" /d "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46565/metro/Dropbox_48x48.png"
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage\eee1e7ca-caac-4cf9-ab6c-7160f41e36f3\Thumbnails"
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage\eee1e7ca-caac-4cf9-ab6c-7160f41e36f3\Thumbnails" /v "Url16x16" /d "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46565/metro/Dropbox_16x16.png"
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage\eee1e7ca-caac-4cf9-ab6c-7160f41e36f3\Thumbnails" /v "Url20x20" /d "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46565/metro/Dropbox_24x24.png"
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage\eee1e7ca-caac-4cf9-ab6c-7160f41e36f3\Thumbnails" /v "Url24x24" /d "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46565/metro/Dropbox_24x24.png"
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage\eee1e7ca-caac-4cf9-ab6c-7160f41e36f3\Thumbnails" /v "Url32x32" /d "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46565/metro/Dropbox_32x32.png"
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage\eee1e7ca-caac-4cf9-ab6c-7160f41e36f3\Thumbnails" /v "Url40x40" /d "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46565/metro/Dropbox_40x40.png"
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Cloud Storage\eee1e7ca-caac-4cf9-ab6c-7160f41e36f3\Thumbnails" /v "Url48x48" /d "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46565/metro/Dropbox_48x48.png"

ECHO.
ECHO Batch file operations complete!
ECHO If you don't see any errors, you can start an Office programme such as Word, click Open or Save As, then click "Add a Place" and choose Dropbox!
```

You can generate a GUID from your favourite search engine, e.g. https://ddg.gg/?q=guid+generator

Answer (score -3):

i added dropbox to office using a batch file which i re designed for office 2016.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9aTuXm3WSl8eWhBQUpGT3JPMTg

just open. press enter. put in your dropbox location and enter. (yes if needed)

did it work? let me know!

Comment: You should reproduce the code here rather than just providing a link that will likely go dead in the future.